# GitLab Pipeline failing with: variables config should be a hash

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

The contents of my .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this:

```yaml
image: python:3.12

variables:
  max_depth: "3"
  max_nodes: "1_000_000"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      variables:
        max_depth: "6"
        max_nodes: "10_000_000"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "dev"
      variables:
        max_depth: "5"
        max_nodes: "5_000_000"

before_script:
  - apt update
  - apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1 libxkbcommon-dev dbus
  - python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  - pip install pipenv
  - pipenv sync -d

stages:
  - static analysis
  - test

mypy:
  stage: static analysis
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - pipenv run mypy project --strict
    - pipenv run mypy test --strict

pylint_project:
  stage: static analysis
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - pipenv run pylint project/**/*.py

pylint_tests:
  stage: static analysis
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - pipenv run pylint test/**/*.py --disable c0116

isort:
  stage: static analysis
  script:
    - pipenv run isort . --check --diff --color
  allow_failure: false

black:
  stage: static analysis
  script:
    - pipenv run black . --check --diff --color --verbose --line-length=79
  allow_failure: false

flake8:
  stage: static analysis
  script:
    - pipenv run flake8 project
  allow_failure: false

test:
  stage: test
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - pipenv run coverage run -m pytest --perft_depth=$max_depth --max_nodes=$max_nodes
    - pipenv run coverage report
    - pipenv run coverage xml
  coverage: '/TOTAL.*\s+(\d+%)$/'
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 30 days
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage.xml
```

I would like to limit the depth and nodes for most pipelines. That is why the default values are low. However, for the main branch and dev branch I would like to have different max_depth and max_nodes values. So I change the default values to other values according to the commit branch name. I have tried to follow the GitLab documentation when writing this.

When I push to my GitLab repo the pipeline fails with: variables config should be a hash.
There are no syntax errors, according to multiple YAML validators. Anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior on gitlab.com -- copy/pasting these contents into the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file works and forms a valid pipeline. Are you sure this is the _exact_ contents of your YAML? Are you using any `include:` statements? The [pipeline editor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/) should allow you to view/validate your configuration. Does that work or not?